# Managing multiple WCF services in one project

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf

Currently I am working on an ERP Project, Using Entity FrameWork and WCF at server side and WPF at client side. Since it is a big project , we have a lot of entities.What we did so far is, Created Service contracts for each Entities and exposed with multiple endpoints.The Problem is we had to add Service Reference for each Service and we are feeling difficult to manage these web services.

1.Is this a proper way ?
if yes,
2.Is there any way to allocate these web services (in classes or folders)..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try grouping them by logical function, not necessarily separate entities.  That sounds a bit too granular to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to keep generating the proxy classes in the client.

Just move the POCO classes and contracts to single assembly which you can reference in the server and client. Then create the necessary channels in the client with ChannelFactory.

[ChannelFactory(TChannel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i wonder if this method can handle the async calls ,and also can i use this method if i don't have control over the service.?

Comment: You need to have control of the service, if you only have the address that exposes the metadata or the generated wsdl then your best bet is svcutil as a prebuild step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with many services you can create routing service which will behave like facade. Once you have routing service defined then all requests are going to be sent towards routing service and then, based on some criteria, provided to specific service. You are dealing with only one service so if any change in sub-services occures, for instance endpoint's address is altered, then such a change needs to be reflected only in routing service.

Comment: Thanks for introducing the Routing Service

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got how to deal with multiple Services

i am considering to use svcutil.exe in order to create proxy classes.
so that we can arrange those classes in folders, and also we can 
get more control over proxies